# Is there no client-side load event for a JSF fragment?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I've been searching a lot to find a way to fire some JS function when a fragment loads. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find an event that I can use inside `af:clientListener` tag which would say, to put it in a literal sense,

> Run this javascript function when the fragment loads

This makes me believe (though could be wrong) that there isn't one available. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an af:poll that fires only once.

Please see if you find this useful:

http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/automatic-adf-popup-opening-on-fragment.html

Comment: Works like charm. +1 and accepted. It's surprising though that we have to make do with such an alternative. A load event would have been more appropriate option.

Comment: Agree, a builtin event would be more natural